# Ubuntu server 16.04 installations have no udev rules

Tags: 16.04, networking, server, ethernet, udev

My Ubuntu desktop 16.04 machine has udev rules:

```
user@desktop:~$ sudo tree /etc/udev/
/etc/udev/
├── hwdb.d
├── rules.d
│   ├── 48-adwits.rules
│   ├── 49-stlinkv1.rules
│   ├── 49-stlinkv2-1.rules
│   ├── 49-stlinkv2.rules
│   ├── 49-stlinkv3.rules
│   ├── 51-android.rules
│   ├── 60-uv4l.rules
│   ├── 65-uv4l_uvc.rules
│   ├── 70-persistent-net.rules
│   └── 85-lpcxpresso.rules
└── udev.conf

2 directories, 11 files
user@desktop:~$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules 
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="f8:b1:56:e8:1b:f4", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", NAME="eth0"
```

but I have two Ubuntu 16.04 server machines which have no rules:

```
user@server1:~$ sudo tree /etc/udev/
/etc/udev/
├── hwdb.d
├── rules.d
└── udev.conf

2 directories, 1 file
```

These servers have four ethernet interfaces each, which are not enumerated in the same order:

Server 1:

```
user@server1:~$ cat /proc/net/bonding/bond* | egrep '(Interface|HW addr)'
Slave Interface: eth0
Permanent HW addr: 34:17:eb:eb:d7:32
Slave Interface: eth1
Permanent HW addr: 6c:b3:11:1b:b5:76
Slave Interface: eth2
Permanent HW addr: 34:17:eb:eb:d7:33
Slave Interface: eth3
Permanent HW addr: 6c:b3:11:1b:b5:77
```

Server 2:

```
user@server2:/etc/udev$ cat /proc/net/bonding/bond* | egrep '(Interface|HW addr)'
Slave Interface: eth0
Permanent HW addr: 34:17:eb:ea:f3:3e
Slave Interface: eth1
Permanent HW addr: 34:17:eb:ea:f3:3f
Slave Interface: eth2
Permanent HW addr: 6c:b3:11:1c:ac:68
Slave Interface: eth3
Permanent HW addr: 6c:b3:11:1c:ac:69
```

The two servers have enumerated their eth interfaces differently.  On server one eth0/eth2 and eth1/eth3 are the names of the dual-nic cards, whereas on server2 its eth0/eth1 and eth2/eth3.

How can I make these servers generate 70-persistent-net.rules files, so that I can edit those to make the two servers have the same interface names for the same rj45 socket positions?

Is there a particular udev package in the desktop release which is missing on the server release, and responsible for the nearly-empty /etc/udev tree?

P.S. The fourth and fifth bytes of all mac addresses have been changed for security, but the leading (manufacturer) bytes, and the last byte have been left alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ähm, Udev rules from system are in `/lib/udev/rules.d/`. Otherwise you would not be able to boot.

```
dpkg -L udev
```

Is one of the Server an upgrade from trusty? Since systemd version 204 cannonical dropped 75-persistent-net-generator.rules and others. [systemd 204](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/204-5ubuntu1)

But own rules in `/etc/udev/rules.d` are read by udev.

Comment: I'm using net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0 to boot the kernel.  Does this mean that there is no way to ensure that eth0..3 are the same sockets on each boot?

Comment: Are the netcards all the same? Or different?

Comment: Dual NICs on the motherboard, from DELL (34:17:eb), dual NICs on an expansion card, from Shenzhen Lianrui Electronics (6c:b3:11).  The problem is that server 1's motherboard NICs are eth0 and eth2, while server 2's motherboard NICs are eth0 and eth1 (and similar confusion for expansion card NICs).

Comment: please follow me to chat. If you want. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101835/ubuntu-server-16-04-installations-have-no-udev-rules